# EOFError with numpy.load()

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, pickle, hdf5

l have a problem loading data of about 70GB using `numpy.load('my_data.npy')` in python2.7

Here is the error  :

```
my_data=np.load('my_data.npy')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 419, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 640, in read_array
    array = pickle.load(fp, **pickle_kwargs)
EOFError
```

My dataset is of shape `(400,300,256,256,19)`

```
dataset=np.asarray(dataset)
numpy.save('my_data.npy',dataset)
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: Tell us about `dataset` - shape, dtype etc

Comment: @hpaulj, please see my update

Comment: Why the `asarray` step?

Comment: l created dataset in a for loop . dataset=[ ]   and dataset.append(). So i need to make in numpy array